# uipopover from uibutton in tableviewcell crashing the application

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uistoryboard, uidatepicker, uipopover

I am using a table view controller in story board which contains a custom table view cell in which a 2 labels and one button is the elements. I need to get a ui popover with date picker when I click on button in custom table view cell. It is not possible to give a direct segue connection from cell to dateViewcontroller as popover.

Please suggest me some ideas.

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToDate"])
{
    DatePickerViewController *dateVC = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] init];
    dateVC =[segue destinationViewController];
    dateVC.delegate = self;

    dateVC.pickerType = @"date";
   _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:dateVC];
    _popover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];

    [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:selectedCell.checkboxBtn.frame inView:selectedCell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];


    // [datePopover setDelegate:self];

}
```

error log is here:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController
>   _commonPresentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]:
>   Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a
>   window.'

Comment: You must post error log alongwith question.

Comment: /Priya xx/xx/xxxxx:1: Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x7fcc0f63e770  <IBProxyObject: 0x7fcc0f63e160> => anchorView => <IBUIButton: 0x7fcc0efa2380>>

Comment: Are you sure selectedCell is in memory or on the view?

Comment: can u make it clear ?

Comment: "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window"  => it mean that your popup should be present on window or in window view hierarchy. So my point is "are you sure your selectedCell is in window view hierarchy?".

Comment: yes, if u refer to the error i commented u may understand the problem i am facing. my scenario is i need a popover from a custom tableview cell in story board. what would u suggest

Comment: Where is selectedCell assigned?